# Brightness and night light not working on Ubuntu 18.04/19.04

Tags: asus, brightness, nvidia-geforce, redshift

Since the very first day I installed Ubuntu on my laptop it has constantly annoyed me with several bugs. I managed to solve some of them myself, but others are still ruining my days.
The reason why I'm asking here is that I cannot take it any longer.

Problem: brightness setting and the night light feature don't work.
Brightness setting never worked for me. I can see the bar, but setting it doesn't change brightness at all.
At the contrary, the night light feature was doing well, until it suddenly stopped working last month.
I also tried to update Ubuntu to 19.04 (I had 18.04) but it didn't solve the problem.

**About my laptop**: ASUS ROG STRIX GL503VM

**About my graphic card**: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 mobile

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Night Light" is not working for me, either, under 19.04 on a Lenovo laptop. But the brightness control does! These are perhaps two separate problems? For me, NL does modify the screen brightness and/or color temp, but within seconds the screen reverts to normal - even if I *don't* close the NL window!